# linker command failed (Apple Mach-O)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker-errors

So, I recently added a pod in my podlife which Xcode suggested me to convert to swift 3, but I later decided to remove this pod but now i can't even run my project (which is really worrying for me since its a big project I'm working on).

I just keep getting this error:

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I tried several things such as cleaning the project etc...

heres the full error log:

> ```
> Ld /Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ego-Test1.app/Ego-Test1
> ```
>
> normal x86_64
>           cd /Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1
>           export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
>           export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Kingfisher
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -F. -FEgo-Test.xcworkspace -FEgo1 -FEgo1.xcworkspace -FEgo1Tests -FEgo1UITests -FPods -FEgo-Test.xcworkspace/xcuserdata -FEgo1.xcworkspace/xcuserdata -FPods/Firebase -FPods/FirebaseAnalytics -FPods/FirebaseAuth -FPods/FirebaseDatabase -FPods/FirebaseInstanceID -FPods/FirebaseStorage -FPods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -FPods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities -FPods/GoogleSymbolUtilities -FPods/GoogleUtilities -FPods/Headers -FPods/Kingfisher -FPods/Local\ Podspecs -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files
>   -FEgo-Test.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/adrienzier.xcuserdatad -FEgo1.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/adrienzier.xcuserdatad -FPods/Firebase/Analytics -FPods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -FPods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks -FPods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -FPods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -FPods/FirebaseInstanceID/Sources -FPods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks -FPods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -FPods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks -FPods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -FPods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -FPods/Headers/Private -FPods/Headers/Public -FPods/Kingfisher/Sources -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Kingfisher -FPods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-Ego-Test1
>   -FEgo1.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/adrienzier.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger -FPods/Firebase/Analytics/Sources -FPods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -FPods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks -FPods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -FPods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks/frameworks -FPods/Headers/Private/Firebase -FPods/Headers/Private/FirebaseInstanceID -FPods/Headers/Public/Firebase -FPods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/build/Release-iphoneos/Kingfisher -filelist /Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Intermediates/Ego-Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ego-Test1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Ego-Test1.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -Xlinker
>   -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Intermediates/Ego-Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ego-Test1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Ego-Test1_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Intermediates/Ego-Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ego-Test1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Ego_Test1.swiftmodule
>   -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework
>   FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseDatabase
>   -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseStorage -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities
>   -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework Kingfisher -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security
>   -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Kingfisher -framework Pods_Ego1 -framework Pods_Ego_Test1 -Xlinker
>   -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Intermediates/Ego-Test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ego-Test1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Ego-Test1_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/adrienzier/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Ego-Test-gqsrlomogkojcvagktneylsgxtey/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Ego-Test1.app/Ego-Test1
>
> ```
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/adrienzier/Desktop/Ego1/build/Release-iphoneos/Kingfisher'
> ld: framework not found Pods_Ego1
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by creating a new project with the same libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Clean project. Go to your target -> Build Phases and remove all pods artifacts:

[image]

You can also use this tool - https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

And before building a project clean it completely - Command + Shift + K

Comment: So i removed all pod artifacts, and i sadly still get the error.